How to configure R on a shared Workstation that deletes user profiles on log off
Hi I have a number of Windows 11 managed workstations. These are in a managed OU for shared computers that deletes the user profile on log off to preserve OS disk space.
I would like to know how/if I can confirgure R so that the library/packages can be installed outside of the user profile & on a different drive letter so they wont get wiped on log off
I am new to using R and do not know where to begin with this or even if it makes sense

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/libPaths.html

in addition to having an understanding of .libPaths() ,  I recommend adopting a project based worklfow, using renv to track a projects dependencies, make use of the global renv cache; and finally make sure you adopt some form of version control on your work, i.e. git.
